# Ambiguous loop on practice exam

Tags: java, loops

I am currently studying for a final exam in Java, and wanted to get a second opinion on something. (some of you may remember me from a day or two ago)
Anyway, a question on the practice exam reads:

> **What is the error in the code?**

```
boolean good = true
while(good = true){
//do stuff
}
```

I feel it is a trick question as the obvious answer would be that this is an infinite loop; however, we do not know what code will be inside the loop, so there could potentially be a break statement or some other form of stepping out of the loop. For my answer I wrote that the condition does not need to be an instantiation, it could just read "while(good){"
What are your thoughts? Thank you much in advance.

Comment: typo , you need a `;` after `= true;`

Comment: I don't feel this question is able to have a definitive answer. If the question was ambiguous on your practice exam, it will also be ambiguous on SO.

Comment: `good = true` is an assignment and will give you always true no matter  of the `good`'s initial value ... otherwise yep it is an infinite loop

Answer (score 5):

`while (good = true)` is an infinite loop. It assigns `true` to `good` and then evaluates `true`. The correct loop would be `while (good == true)` **or** `while (good)`

Comment: This issue is that this is not a compiler error. We can only assume it's a logic error, but without knowing the code inside the loop and what the intended behavior is, `good = true` could just be a way to reset the flag before each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, the issue is that you are *reassigning* the value of good, every time the loop iterates.

This is exactly the reason many professional developers will write their statements *backwards* like

```
while ( true == good )
vs
while ( good == true )
```

and

```
if ( null == a )
vs
if ( a == null )
```

Reason being, in the event of a typo, such as the one posted in your question, both

```
while ( true = good )
if ( null = a )
```

will throw compiler errors, as you are trying to assign a value to a constant.